# Dynamically generated navbar and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I could not find an easy way to explain the following, so I apologize if it is not clear enough.

I have a navigation bar where each item is a category of articles. The navigation item are read from database and can be modified from the back-office.

I get the categories via a AngularJS controller :

```js
app.controller('ApiController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('/categories')
        .success(function(categories) {
            $scope.categories = categories;
        });
}]);
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="target-navbar-main">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-repeat="category in categories">
            <a href="/<% category.slug %>" title="<% category.name %>"><% category.name %></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In the body of the page, I am using another controller to get articles of a given category but I can't find a way to make the navbar communicate with the articles controller and pass the category of the clicked button.

Thanks for help

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle link with more code so we have a better understanding of what your code looks like.

Comment: Difficult to get a working jsfiddle due to database dependency : http://jsfiddle.net/vkg4xctq/

Comment: I end up using SPA pattern with AngularJS routing instead of Laravel routing and a ng-view.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want for the API is a service not a controller. Generally in Angular controllers aren't meant to be sending a bunch of data between each other. Central sets of calls and communications that multiple controllers depend on are put into services. If you were to extract your API calls to a service you could inject that service into that controllers that need to deal with it as necessary. But without seeing  more of the code in question it's hard to recommend a good way to do that.